# How to do something when scroll to content or content appear on window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a lot of pictures on my page. and I want to do some javascript and PHP processing when the user scrolls down to each image. I have come up with the follwing:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    hT = $('.Picture-1A:eq(3)').offset().top,
    hH = $('.Picture-1A:eq(3)').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ((wS >= (hT+hH-wH))){
        alert('you have scrolled to the h1!');
    }
});
```

The above example only works if I reach to a certain image. And I want to do something when the scroll reach an image. I want to get it's ID and process that in PHP using AJAX.

Let's assume that the following are the images:

```
<div class="Picture-1A"></div>
<div class="Picture-1A"></div>
<div class="Picture-1A"></div>
```

What I want to do is add 1 impression to the image that has appeared on the window. and I want to do that using AJAX every time the user scrolls down the page.

That's it

**Update:**
I have found a great library thanks to Eugenio Enko. and here is how it's done:

1. Include the library code in your project after jQuery:
2. If you want it to trigger for each image, then use each like so:

   ```
      $('.Picture-1A').each(function() {
         $(this).waypoint(function(direction){
             alert($(this).html());
         });
      });
   ```

But I am having trouble getting the html of `$(".Picture-1A").html()` using `this` it returns undefiend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can view an example using the old waypoint:

http://codepen.io/eugenioenko/pen/qZMqOW

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.spfx-scroll-p').waypoint(function(){
      alert('scrolled');
    },{offset:'90%'});
});
```

Comment: Hi I have updated the question with some new question. Please help me it won't take long. Thanks

Comment: I think you dond´t need to use $.each() function.

`$('.Picture-1Ap').waypoint(function(){console.log($(this).html()); },{offset:'90%'}); });`

should do the trick, waypoint already uses each.
offset 90% means that the element should be at 90% of the screen. 50% would mean right in the middle.

Comment: it worked without each, great. But what about getting the picture id? how can I get the picture id when I scroll to it?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two libraries I know that could help you with that:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

http://scrollmagic.io/

The second one is more complete and has much more option, but for what you need, it seems that waypoint should work well enough.

best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the referral. Do you know how can I use it for class instead of id?

Comment: You could use jquery api: 

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/
`code`
var waypoints = $('.options-only').waypoint({
`code`